# How to apply decorator to all blueprint urls in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a blueprint and some url functions,

```
admin_bp = Blueprint('admin', __name__)

@admin_bp.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', ])
@flask_login.login_required
def dashboard():

    context = {}

    page = 'admin/dashboard.html'
    return render_template(page, **context)

@admin_bp.route('/deny', methods=['GET', ])
@flask_login.login_required
def deny():
    return 'hey bro you dont belong here'
```

I don't want to copy paste `@flask_login.login_required` decorator for all url functions under this blueprint. Is there a better way that I can apply decorator for all blueprint urls?

Answer (score 19):

You can add `before_request()` as a function that will run before each request in a view.

You will then want to add decorators to inject additional functionality to the `before_request` function. You will want to import the `login_required` decorator to ensure each endpoint requires a logged in user. This decorator is part of the `flask_login` library.

Since it looks like your views are part of an admin, I'd also recommend adding a custom decorator to your `before_request` function with something like `@role_required('admin')`. The functionality for that decorator will live somewhere else and be imported.

```
@admin_bp.before_request
@login_required
def before_request():
    """ Protect all of the admin endpoints. """
    pass
```

Comment: Hi, instead of adding login_required, I'm using the jwt_required, but it's the same principal, I think. But, I still get inside the body of the function before_request, even if the @jwt_required is not fullfilled. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `Blueprint` and override the `route` method.

```
import flask

class MyBlueprint(flask.Blueprint):
  def route(self, rule, **options):
    def decorator(f):
      # these lines are copied from flask.Blueprint.route
      endpoint = options.pop("endpoint", f.__name__)
      self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)

      # At this point flask.Blueprint.route simply returns f.
      # But you can nest a decorator.
      def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        # stuff you want to do before each request goes here
        try:
          result = f(*args, **kwargs)
          # stuff you want to do on successful responses (probing status, headers, etc.) goes here
        except Exception as e:
          # stuff you want to do on error responses goes here
          raise
      return inner
```

Now use the new subclass in your blueprints:

```
-v1_blueprint = Blueprint('v1', __name__)
+v1_blueprint = MyBlueprint('v1', __name__)
```

No changes needed to individual routes.

The drawback of this approach is that it copies code from inside Flask. If the implementation of `flask.Blueprint.route` were to change in a future version, you'd need to sync MyBlueprint with it when you upgrade Flask.

Comment: I couldn't build something similar for flask_restx's `Namespace` :(

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the user first:

```
from flask.ext.login import current_user


@admin_bp.before_request
def check_user():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated():
        abort(401)

# your other functions without `@flask_login.login_required`
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the general question, which might include code meant to execute *after* a request, not just before it. The **@after_request** function  decorates functions that take a response object as input, but somebody might want to pre-process the route's returned value before it becomes responsified.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on top of @kartik answer

I tried to do the same and specifically I needed a decorated functionality (unlike @Robert) answer which supplied a solution using `before_request` which is a middleware and doesn't wrap the function itself, because my problem required decoration to profile the code.

I solved it without copying the code from Flask's `Scaffold` class.
We just need to override and pass our wrapped function to the decorator that flask creates.
Of course `my_decorator` can be any decorator you need.

```py
import typing as t
from functools import wraps

from flask import Flask


def my_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Entering {f.__name__}")
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"Finished {f.__name__}")
        return result

    return inner


class MyFlask(Flask):
    def route(self, rule: str, **options: t.Any) -> t.Callable:
        route_decorator = super().route(rule, **options)

        def inner(f):
            new_f = my_decorator(f)
            return route_decorator(new_f)

        return inner


app = MyFlask("app")


@app.route("/test")
def test():
    print("In test")
    return {}


app.run()
```

Then, running:

```py
import requests
requests.get("http://localhost:5000/test")
```

Prints

```
Entering test
In test
Finished test
```